# Inject CRUD Repository in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, repository

I can't Inject CRUD Repository in Spring.

Repository

```html
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<entity,Long>{    
}
```

```
@Autowired EntityRepository eR
```

Error:
.. Required a Bean of Type `EntityRepository` that could not be found

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'EntityRepository' in your configuration.
```

My main

```html
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"de.xyz.*"}) 
@EntityScan("de.xyz.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("de.xyz.*") 
//@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is using the basePackages field; which is a field inside ComponentScan annotation.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.xyz.repository"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    //  
}
```

Comment: i have a @Configuration's Class to define which class should be injected where and how etc the functions looks something like this https://pastebin.com/iXHBuaHr

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 :**
Try to include both the classes in the same package. This way you can narrow down the issue of component scanning. Remove all other annotations and keep only @SpringBootApplication

```
Note : 
By default spring loads all the classes under the package of Application Class.
```

**Step2 :** See your dependencies, verify you have included the dependencies for JPA repositories.

**Step3 :** Post the GIT Hub link of the code, so that it can be looked further.

Otherwise add all the packages inside the component scan annotation , Like below.
@ComponentScan({ "a.b.c", "a.b.c.dao" })

As you have mentioned there is a configuration class which is creating the beans, try to include that class package in the same package or include it in component scan.

Hope this help.